# How to determine if email is from from gaia.bounces.google.com or just forwarded from there?

Tags: email, spam, gmail

Shown below are the "from and to" portions of the message. It looks like it is just forwarded by "gaia.bounces.google.com". The message itself (and I have quite a few of them) indicates I have been awarded something by some recognizable brands.

```
from:   Poshmark Winner <info_ijel5757@cbypxrs.trucksspoon.org> via gaia.bounces.google.com 
to: khvkeqokmzZE@gmail.com
cc: khvkeqokmzNV@gmail.com
date:   Nov 4, 2023, 12:50 PM
subject:    message#3083898,for-khvkeqokmz
mailing list:   <7202588.xt.local> Filter messages from this mailing list
mailed-by:  gaia.bounces.google.com
unsubscribe:    Unsubscribe from this mailing list
security:    Standard encryption (TLS) Learn more
```

Comment: Nothing is "from" gaia.bounces.google.com. As you can see in what you posted, it's from `trucksspoon.org`. This is more of an email-handling question than a security question. You can also use online tools (https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/) to give you more info.